# assertNotNull fails at AndroidStudio, when calling a method with String return

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

What I got, is a couple of methods to generate AES key. I'm doing test cases over it, but when I try to pass a test to verify it returns the String of the AES key, it fails.

The method to call is:

```
public String getAESString() {
     return Base64.encodeToString(this.aesKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

and the test: (the `setupAES` just call the generate AES method that it's already tested)

```
@Test
    public void getAESString() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        setupAes();
        assertNotNull(cryptoMancer.getAESString());
    }
```

But I know, that the method getAesString, is working fine, because I'm using it a test Activity, and I can used it, without problems.

How can I avoid this error? (I mean, how I pass the test)

The error log i'm getting is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)
    at es.in2.rsa_aes_testing.CryptoMancerTest.getAESString(CryptoMancerTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Image, that shows the method working perfect in the app:

[image]

Comment: Try stepping through it in the debugger and verify that the return value is actually what you expect it to be. 

The 'assertion fail' error - would indicate that the value you're running your assertion against has a non-null value.

Comment: but if I change the assertion, to: `assertFalse(cryptMancer.getAESString().isEmpty())` , it fails, telling me that I'm trying t acces to a null object... :/

Comment: Hmm..strange, do have a look at the code in the debugger, it seems this code may not be behaving as you are expecting it to.

Comment: Which `Base64` class are you using? I take it that it’s not `java.util.Base64`?

Comment: It seems that you *are* getting `null` from your method, even if this was completely unexpected.

Comment: @OleV.V. the import is `android.util.Base64` . But if I try to change to `java.util.Base64` is marked in red (like if not exist)

Comment: In that case the docs for `encodeToString (byte[], int)` say “return a newly allocated String with the result”. This doesn’t sound like `null` could be returned. Weird.

Comment: It couldn’t be that `this.aesKey.getEncoded()` could return null and `encodeToString()` then could return `null` in reply to receiving a `null`? Doesn’t sound very likely, I admit.

Comment: Yes I read it, and is a strange behaviour, because if I use this method in the test activity, is working perfect (add Image to question)

Comment: Is the same `setupAes()` method that you are calling in the code you posted also called when you run the test activity where your `getAESString()` works perfectly ? Is the `cryptoMancer` instance equal ?